# Xcode project has live issues for macOS but not for iOS

Tags: xcode

We have an Xcode project that supports both iOS and macOS. The project has different schemas for each platform and two separate application targets, but most of the code is in framework targets which are shared between both platforms. Both schemas can be built without errors, so building generally not a problem and works as expected.

However, while editing the code, only the macOS schema presents live issues (compiler errors and warnings while editing). When we switch to the iOS scheme, no errors are displayed while editing the code. And if we trigger a full iOS build and there were build errors, the errors are briefly displayed in the source code editor, but disappear after a few seconds, so only the build log tells us what went wrong.

As a workaround, we found that disabling live issues (`Preferences > General > Show live issues`) at least ensures that the build errors of the last manually triggered build are permanently displayed in the editor. While this is already a huge improvement, these errors are not updated until we trigger another build, which is still a bit annoying and time consuming. When we use the macOS scheme, everything works like a charm.

The problem equally appears in Xcode 13.x and Xcode 14.x, no matter the exact version. Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible reasons why this might happen. What happens in general is that the background linting process fails in such a way, that no issues at all are produced and because issues reported by the background linting process override the issues reported by the last build, the issues of the last build briefly appear and then vanish again.

Personally I consider that a rather stupid bug in Xcode since when the linting process has failed, Xcode should not replace the issues from the last build with an empty issue list from the linting process, after all it is aware that linting has failed and that this is the true reason why the issue list is empty and not because the linter found no issues anymore.

To fix that problem, you need to figure out why the background linting process fails. Therefore you open a Terminal and start Xcode like this:

```sh
SOURCEKIT_LOGGING=3 /<path-to-xcode>/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode 2>xcode.txt
```

Then just edit any file to make the linter run in background and quit Xcode again. Open the file `xcode.txt` and search for the name of the source file you just edited. It might appear multiple times but you are looking for an entry that looks as follows:

```json
[date] [time] Xcode[...] SourceKit-client: [...] {
  key.compilerargs: [
    "-x",
    "objective-c",
    "-ivfsoverlay",
:
   ]
```

These are the compiler arguments used for linting the file. To convert the arguments to shell format, just copy everything between `[` and the closing `]` (it's a JSON array) and do a regex search and replace for `,\n$` and replace it with nothing (empty string). This gives you a single line with all arguments correctly quoted.

Now you can call the compiler yourself in Terminal with these arguments and see exactly where the problem is. Depending on the kind of file, the compiler is either `clang` (c, objc), `clang++` (c++, objc++), or `swiftc` (swift). You should be getting an error that at least provides you a hint where the problem is.

Usually a header or module is not found, which would also be a problem when building the project in Xcode, yet during the build process sometimes the issue is fixed as components are built in a specific order, can be found in the build target dir during the build, or parts of the build configuration is dynamically overridden. None of that happens when the linter runs. Xcode heavily depend on all project settings being correct and all implicit dependencies being detectable or configured as explicit dependencies when generating the linting arguments. Also build script phases that do some kind of voodoo magic to make building even possible can be a big issue as those won't run either.

Once you have figured out the linter error but have no idea how to fix it, just post a new question here on SO and ask for help. Now that you have the exact error message, it will be much easier to give you advice without just guessing in the dark.